# Python 3.7.3 SyntaxError variable used prior to global declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I get the following error:

[image]

For this code:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NpuQqXbFlkDOjHudIy2dOC8tb1ZA7JXhFUy94Vvl5YU/edit

FYI: This is not my coding but I'll be using it for my project and I have zero knowledge on python because just started to use it.

Comment: Please include code as text, don't link it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you wrote `global car_sensed` after using it.
Here is the problem:

```
def car_arrive():
    dist1 = distance_1()
    dist2 = distance_2()

    if car_sensed == True: # You use car_sensed here
        if dist1<10:
            global car_sensed
            # You mark it as global here, after using it
            # which the interpreter complains about
            lcd.message('Car Parked.')
```

You simply have to move all your global statements to the top of the function. After fixing it looks like this:

```
def car_arrive():
    global car_sensed

    dist1 = distance_1()
    dist2 = distance_2()

    if car_sensed == True:
        if dist1<10:
            lcd.message('Car Parked.')
            time.sleep(2)
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.message('Welcome.')
            parkingA=True #car parked in parking A
            #vacant.remove('A')
            car_sensed = False
        
        else:
            parkingA=False

        if dist2<10:
            lcd.message('Car Parked.')
            time.sleep(2)
            lcd.clear()
            lcd.message('Welcome.')
            parkingB=True #car parked in parking B
            #vacant.remove('B')
            car_sensed = False
                
        else:
            parkingB=False
```

I should mention however, that using global variables is not recommended.